# How to cast datetime of mysql to datetime of asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am fetching date from a table called lot in mysql in a string and want to insert that same datetime value in another table called soldlot in mysql. How to do that? Please help.

Thank you

```
String q6 = "select date from lot LIMIT " + m + "," + n + "";
MySqlCommand c6 = new MySqlCommand(q6, cn);
String d = (String)(c6.ExecuteScalar());
String q7 = "insert into sold values(" + lotno + "," + c + "," + rcno + ",'" + d.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd") + "')";
MySqlCommand c7 = new MySqlCommand(q7, cn);
c7.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: What error do you get.  Does q7 contain valid SQL after the first query?

Comment: Should `d` be a `DateTime` rather than a `String`?

Comment: `d.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd")` will use minutes instead of Month, since lower case `mm` is for minutes, and upper case `MM` is for month, **But more importantly** use Parameters and don't pass your dates as string.

Comment: You should be aware that your code is vulnerable to sql injection - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Also `ExecuteScalar` will only let you return a single value which makes the parameterised `LIMIT` semi pointless.

Comment: I tried with Datetime. But the casting is not being done since the datetime formats are different. I tried "MM" also, but to no avail.

Comment: This is for my major project. It urgent.So if anyone can, please help me out!

Comment: > "`I tried with Datetime. But the casting is not being done since the datetime formats are different`" That only makes sense if the `date` column in your `lot` table is some kind of string type (varchar, nchar, etc), rather than a real datetime type. If you use a datetime type, format and casting never enter into it: the MySql .Net provider takes care of it for you, and a .Net DateTime is pulled back from the DB. Also, that sql injection issue is pretty awful.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn -The date column in my mysql table is of the type "DATE". Mysql saves date in the format "yyyy-mm-dd" whereas asp.net saves the date in the format "dd-mm-yyyy", hence Im unable to typecast. Please help.

Comment: You are mistaken on both counts. ASP.Net keeps datetime variables in a binary format that's not human readable, and only shows you that format in the debugger or after converting to a string (which you should **not** be doing for SQL). The MySQL docs do say that the DATE type is _retrieved_ in that format, but don't specify how it's _stored_. It's likely MySql is doing something similar to ADO.Net for efficiency. Regardless, the MySQL ADO.Net provider that transports data between MySQL and .Net uses the ASP.Net format for returning Date variables.

Comment: Also, why even retrieve this date? Why not just use a `SELECT` in your insert?

Comment: How do I do that? If you could write down the code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's fix this to use parameters:

```
//I'm less worried about this query, as m and are likely integers. 
// I still don't approve of the string concatenation, but I'll leave it alone for now
String q6 = "select date from lot LIMIT " + m + "," + n + "";
MySqlCommand c6 = new MySqlCommand(q6, cn);
DateTime d = (DateTime)c6.ExecuteScalar(); //This should work just fine. 


//but parameters are VERY IMPORTANT for this query
String q7 = "insert into sold values( @LotNo, @c, @rcno, @date );";
MySqlCommand c7 = new MySqlCommand(q7, cn);
//I'm guessing at column types. Use actual DB column types and lengths here
c7.Parameters.Add("@LotNo", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 6).Value = lotno;
c7.Parameters.Add("@c", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = c;
c7.Parameters.Add("@rcno", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 6).Value = rcno;
c7.Parameters.Add("@date", MySQlDbType.Date).Value = d;

c7.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This change will fix a *very serious* security issue in your code, and as a nice side effect also avoids any need to ever think about date formats, thus answering your question at the same time.

But while I'm here, let's also make one other big improvement to this. Let's save an entire round-trip to the database, and consolidate your two queries into one:

```
String q6 = "insert into sold select @LotNo, @c, @rcno, date from lot LIMIT @m , @n;";
MySqlCommand c6 = new MySqlCommand(q6, cn);
//I'm guessing at column types. Use actual DB column types and lengths here
c6.Parameters.Add("@LotNo", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 6).Value = lotno;
c6.Parameters.Add("@c", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = c;
c6.Parameters.Add("@rcno", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 6).Value = rcno;
c6.Parameters.Add("@m", MySqlDbType.Int).Value = m;
c6.Parameters.Add("@n", MySqlDbType.Int).Value = n;

c6.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If the first attempt didn't solve your date casting issue, this will, as now the date never need come over to ASP.Net at all, and this will be **much** faster as a bonus.

Finally, I'm concerned that you were already up to #7 on your q and c variables. That's a major code smell for me. Always try to reduce the number of round-trips to the database. Mostly likely, everything in this method can be written as a single SQL statement, or at least reduced to a two-step process.

Comment: Im getting this error on the line DateTime d= (DateTime) c6.executescalar();System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: You may be getting a NULL back, but it doesn't really matter: go right to the second code snippet, which makes this whole thing unnecessary.

Comment: Also: this page from the Connector/Net docs may be useful: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-datetime-invalid.html

Comment: Thank you so much @Joel Coehoorn for the help :) Its working.

Comment: Im coding for the first time in c#, trying to learn it from the internet. Thank you for guiding.